# Dante server Pam authentication does not work

Tags: proxy, pam, debian-jessie, socks, dante

So I configured `Dante 1.4.2` (compiled it from source on Debian 8.7 which runs on MS Azure) and followed their official configuration guide to run my SOCKS5 server. I created a firewall rule to accept incoming connection on port `1080 tcp`. I used Mozilla Firefox to connect to it. It works fine when there is no authentication. However, I cannot connect when I set `socksmethod: pam.username`. I'm also quite sure that Dante was compiled with pam support (`build: libwrap mon-data mon-disconnect pam preload sess2`)

This is my `/etc/sockd.conf`

```
#logging
errorlog: /home/toto/Logs/sockd.errlog
logoutput: /home/toto/Logs/sockd.log
#debug: 1

# The listening network interface or address.
internal: eth0 port = 1080

# The proxying network interface or address.
external: eth0

#server identities (not needed on solaris)
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody
#user.libwrap: libwrap

#reverse dns lookup
#srchost: nodnsmismatch

# client-rules determine who can connect to the internal interface.
# The default of "none" permits anonymous access.
clientmethod: none

# socks-rules determine what is proxied through the external interface.
# The default of "none" permits anonymous access.
socksmethod: pam.username

#standard client rule, accept all clients
client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect disconnect error
        socksmethod: pam.username
}

#outgoing traffic, requiring pam.username authentication, as specified
#in the global socksmethod.
socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        command: bind connect udpassociate
        log: connect disconnect error
        socksmethod: pam.username
}
```

Socks does not seems to bind to my internal address. The log file says: `failed to bind internal addresses: Address already in use` The internal address is behind an NAT so that could be the problem.

If I remove `bind` from config it starts but throws the message: `block(1): tcp/accept ]: 199.217.115.228.9069 10.0.0.6.1080: error after reading 3 bytes in 0 seconds: client offered no acceptable authentication method` , these log entries continue (each with different address) until I end the server process.

Also my `/etc/pam.d/sockd`

```
account    required     pam_nologin.so
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    required     pam_limits.so
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check if you are sending your username and password when connecting.

```
client offered no acceptable authentication method
```

it seems nothing was sent by the client.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a client issue, i.e Firefox does not know how to authenticate SOCKS5 properly. Better use a browser extension